# TestNG - running specific tests programmatically

Tags: java, testng

I am trying to create testng.xml programmatically. I use below Java code

```
public static createTestSuit(String testClass){
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("My Suite");
    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setName("My Test");
    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    classes.add(new XmlClass(testClass));
    test.setXmlClasses(classes) ;
    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    suites.add(suite);
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    tng.run();
}
```

The class 'testClass' contains several test methods. I don't want to run all these methods. How can I specify only the test method names that I want to run in above code, so that the above method should look something like

```
public static createTestSuit(String testClass, List<String> testCasesID){
      //code
}
```

Note: My test methods are in the form

```
   @Test(testName="testCaseID")
    public void test1(){
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `XmlInclude` to include only those test methods that you want.

```
XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass("");
List<XmlInclude> includeMethods = new ArrayList<>();
includeMethods.add(new XmlInclude("test1"));
xmlClass.setIncludedMethods(includeMethods);
```

If include methods list is not defined or defined empty then TestNG will run all tests in a class. Otherwise it'll run only included tests by their method names.

Comment: This code works fine, but is there any way to specify 'testName' instead of  method name with 'includeMethods'?

Comment: @curious I'm not sure whether testNG has this feature since there's no guarantee that you'll give all your tests unique names. But you can always traverse the classes yourself, find the methods you want by their annotations and pass those methods to TestNG

Answer (score 2):

the below code works perfectly to generate the TestNG xml by selecting the Methods which needs to be executed in a particular class.

```
    //Creating TestNG object
    TestNG myTestNG = new TestNG();

    //Creating XML Suite
    XmlSuite mySuite = new XmlSuite();

    //Setting the name for XML Suite
    mySuite.setName("My Suite");

    //Setting the XML Suite Parallel execution mode as Methods
    mySuite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.METHODS);

    //Adding the Listener class to the XML Suite
    mySuite.addListener("test.Listener1");

    //Creating XML Test and add the Test to the Suite
    XmlTest myTest = new XmlTest(mySuite);

    //Setting the name for XML Test
    myTest.setName("My Test");

    //Setting the Preserve Order for XML Test to True to execute the Test in Order
    myTest.setPreserveOrder("true");

    //Creating HashMap for setting the Parameters for the XML Test 
    HashMap<String,String> testngParams = new HashMap<String,String> ();
    testngParams.put("browserName", "Chrome"); 
    testngParams.put("browserVersion","81"); 
    myTest.setParameters(testngParams);

    //Creating XML Class
    XmlClass myClass = new XmlClass("test.MainTest1");

    //Creating XML Include in the form of ArrayList to add Multiple Methods which i need to run from the Class
    List<XmlInclude> myMethods = new ArrayList<>();
    myMethods.add(new XmlInclude("method1"));
    myMethods.add(new XmlInclude("method2"));

    //Adding the Methods selected to the my XML Class defined
    myClass.setIncludedMethods(myMethods);

    //Getting the Classes and adding it to the XML Test defined
    myTest.getClasses().add(myClass);

    //Creating XML Suite in the form of ArrayList and adding the list of Suites defined
    List<XmlSuite> mySuitesList = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    mySuitesList.add(mySuite);

    //Adding the XMLSuites selected to the TestNG defined
    myTestNG.setXmlSuites(mySuitesList);

    //Setting the execution Thread Count for Parallel Execution
    mySuite.setThreadCount(10);

    //Setting the Verbose Count for Console Logs
    mySuite.setVerbose(2);

    //Executing the TestNG created
    myTestNG.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can skip the test using annotation enabled=false

```
 @Test(testName="testCaseID" enabled="false")
 public void test1(){
    //code here..
 }
```